# OneLogin - Create app api (AWS)

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, onelogin

I have a use case where we need to often add additional aws login apps to our onelogin for various clients. I do not want to give everyone permission to do this but would like to set up an API that can take inputs of all the information and then create the app and return what is needed for aws.

I don't see a create app api on the developers page. Is there a way to do this? Is it on the road map? Am I missing anything?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

We've got a roadmap item to implement this (something that would take in Metadata and create an app)

Having said that, please check out the [AWS multi-account, multi-role connector](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/212802926-Configuring-SAML-for-Amazon-Web-Services-AWS-with-Multiple-Accounts-and-Roles). This automates a lot of the user access headaches around AWS and allows you to use our rules engine to assign users to multiple roles in multiple AWS accounts through a single connector.

Basically you can set up rules to grant Roles in OneLogin access to roles in AWS and then delegate the administration of those roles to different admins.